# Swift Play Video cant display

Tags: ios, xcode, video, swift

### Heading

i'm try to Play the Video with Swift.
i use this code to change UIController

```
var vc = playVideoOne()
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

this is my PlayVideo Code

```
var audioplayer:MPMoviePlayerController=MPMoviePlayerController()
var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://dev.fjuts.com:83/test.mp4")!
self.audioplayer.contentURL = url
audioplayer.play()
self.view.addSubview(audioplayer.view)
```

but the Video Sound is output. Video is not output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your function like this:

```
var audioplayer : MPMoviePlayerController!

var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://dev.fjuts.com:83/test.mp4")

audioplayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)

audioplayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)

audioplayer.view.sizeToFit()

audioplayer.play()

self.view.addSubview(audioplayer.view)

audioplayer.fullscreen = true

audioplayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
```

May be this can help you..